# Apple thinks I'm my father

Tags: macos, icloud, automator

My mac thinks I'm my father. When in automator I do this:

```
[get value of variable: name] --> [new text file. Save as 'name.txt'. Location: desktop]
```

it should put my name in a text file and put it on the desktop. But instead it puts my fathers name in there.

Why?

My Apple ID, iCloud account and all info on my mac and connected social media is on my name. But it still thinks I'm my father.

Could you please help?

[image: dutch version]

Comment: If you go into the accounts pane in System Preferences and select your account, the Name field has your own name?

Comment: Yes. Also on http://appleid.apple.com

Comment: Can you poste more or your automator workflow? Where does 'Haal waarde van variablele op' ('Get Value of Variable') get it's input from?

Comment: Just from the osx system I guess?

Comment: Basicly the variable is the input and it puts it into a text file which is the output

Comment: What comes before "[get value of variable: name]" in this workflow?

Comment: Nothing comes there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check on the address book if your father's contact has `myself: me` assigned.

If it does, remove it and assign it in your contact.

[image]

Comment: ill try tomorrow!